# Receiving Infinity Value

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a unit conversion program but I keep receiving value as infinity. I'm not sure where I need to fix since it's not giving me errors. I only tested oz to ml to make sure I'm doing it correctly but I'm receiving infinity as the answer.

**UnitConverter.java**:

```
public class UnitConverter {

    final double oz_TO_ml = 29.5735; 
    final double gal_TO_g = 3.78541;
    final double lb_TO_kg = 0.453592;
    final double inc_TO_mm = 25.4;//Inc is inches
    final double ft_TO_cm = 30.48;
    final double mi_TO_km = 1.60934;

    double factor;

    public UnitConverter(String unit) {
        if (unit.equals("oz")) {
            factor = oz_TO_ml;
        } else if (unit.equals("gal")) {    
            factor = gal_TO_g;
        } else if (unit.equals("lb")) {     
            factor = lb_TO_kg;
        }
    }

    public double toOz(double amount) {
        return (amount * factor);
    }

    public double fromOz(double amount) {
        return (amount / factor);
    }

    public double toMl(double amount) {
        return (amount * factor);
    }

    public double fromMl(double amount) {
        return (amount / factor);
    }
}
```

**Calculator.java**:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Convert from: ");
        String fromUnit = in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Convert to: ");
        String toUnit = in.nextLine();

        UnitConverter from = new UnitConverter(fromUnit);
        UnitConverter to = new UnitConverter(toUnit);

        System.out.print("Value ");
        double val = in.nextDouble();

        double oz = from.toOz(val);
        double converted = to.fromOz(oz);

        System.out.println(val + " " + fromUnit + " = " + converted + " " + toUnit);
    }
}
```

**Sample input**:

```
Convert from: oz
Convert to: ml
Value 12
```

**Output**:

```
12.0 oz = Infinity ml
```

Comment: What did you type when you ran it?

Comment: And what was the result of your system out statement

Comment: @immibis i ran it and typed in oz when it asked convert from: and then typed ml for conver to: and 12 for value

Comment: And what conversion factor does your program use for "ml"?

Comment: @abcdef this is what is says when i run it. Convert from: 
Convert to: 
Value

Comment: @immibis i just have the oz to ml right now.

Comment: As abcdef answered, you don't do anything when passing in `ml`. Check my answer for a detailed analysis of your code.

Comment: What does it mean to convert "oz" to "ml" anyway?  Doesn't it depend on the substance?

Comment: Fluid ounces can be converted to ml, but not mass/weight (depends on density). Those are converted to grams.

Comment: @AaronD yes. i will be adding an System.exit(1);. hopefully that fixes the program if someone inputs an invalid unit conversion

Answer (score 1):

Your `UnitConverter` class constructor only knows about 3 units: `oz`, `gal`, and `lb`. If you instantiate it with one of those, it will correctly assign the factor and be able to convert units, as seen below:

```
public UnitConverter(String unit) {
    if (unit.equals("oz")) {
        factor = oz_TO_ml;
    } else if (unit.equals("gal")) {    
        factor = gal_TO_g;
    } else if (unit.equals("lb")) {     
        factor = lb_TO_kg;
    }
}
```

However, in your Calculator class, you have this line:

```
UnitConverter from = new UnitConverter(fromUnit);
UnitConverter to = new UnitConverter(toUnit);
```

If you run your program with your sample input, from is `oz` and to is `ml`. But if you instantiate `UnitConverter` with the unit `ml`, what does factor get set to? According to your constructor, it is never set, and so it retains its default value of `0.0`.

Later, you call this line:

```
double converted = to.fromOz(oz);
```

This runs the `fromOz` method

```
public double fromOz(double amount) {
    return (amount / factor);
}
```

Which divides by the factor, which is `0.0`. This is the source of your Infinity output.

As the other answer says, you don't need to have two `UnitConverter` objects to perform this calculation. The factor is correct to convert between ounces and millilitres, so this Calculator code is sufficient.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Convert from: ");
        String fromUnit = in.nextLine();

        UnitConverter from = new UnitConverter(fromUnit);

        System.out.print("Value ");
        double val = in.nextDouble();

        double result = from.toMl(val);

        System.out.println(val + " " + fromUnit + " = " + result + " ml.");
    }
}
```

If you wanted to keep your current calculator code, you would need to add a condition in your `UnitConverter` constructor for a scalefactor for ml (`1.0`). However, I think this approach is flawed because what happens, for example, when you try to convert between oz and inches? The conversion makes no sense but your architecture would not prevent it.

Comment: Great answer, it describes the problem well and has a much better solution

Answer (score 1):

```
public UnitConverter(String unit)
{ 
       if (unit.equals("oz")) 
       { 
           factor = oz_TO_ml; 
        } else if (unit.equals("gal")) 
        { 
            factor = gal_TO_g; 
        } else if (unit.equals("lb")) 
        { factor = lb_TO_kg; 
        } 
  }
```

If you pass "ml" the factor will be zero

Your design currently needs two of these but you really only need one as "oz" has everything it needs to do the conversion.

Ignore the the toUnit in your line input code and just use fromUnit

Edit : I'll show you an alternative way to do things, it just supports one convert to show the rough design. Note the method calls are now static because you will only ever need one instance of them

UnitConverter.java

```
public class UnitConverter 
{

  private static final double oz_TO_ml = 29.5735;    

  public static double convert(String fromType, String toType,double amount) throws IllegalArgumentException
  {
      if (fromType.equals("oz") && toType.equals("ml"))
      {
          return (amount * oz_TO_ml);
      }
      else
      {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("The combination of converting " + fromType + " to " + toType + " is not supported");
      }
  }    
}
```

Calculator.java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Convert from: ");
    String fromUnit = in.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Convert to: ");
    String toUnit = in.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Value ");
    double val = in.nextDouble();

    System.out.println(val + " " + fromUnit + " = " + UnitConverter.convert(fromUnit,toUnit,val) + " " + toUnit);
}
```

}

Comment: what do you mean pass "ml"? im kind of lost right now

Comment: UnitConverter to = new UnitConverter(toUnit);  <-  this line here you pass the text ml. Your constructor does not know about the string ml

Comment: oh okay. How do i fix that?

Comment: I tried just ignoring the toUnit and it gave me an syntax error

Comment: @immibis it's suppose to work by putting the values of each unit im converting to but i keep getting infinity as the answer of the converted unit

Comment: @Jay In other words you don't know.

Comment: @immibis I guess so. Should I just restart then?

Comment: @Jay I think he's suggesting that you take a step back and really try to make an effort to understand the problem in the first place. No one ever succeeded in solving a problem without understanding what that problem was. Once you really understand the problem, the right approach to solving that problem will come to you more easily.

Comment: @jay : I echo inmibis: The fix for the code is either initialize the factor variable with one. A double Factor = 1;

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the factor varible with one. A java with default give 0 to primitive double,

```
   class UnitConvertor {

    final double oz_TO_ml = 29.5735; 
    final double gal_TO_g = 3.78541;
    final double lb_TO_kg = 0.453592;
    final double inc_TO_mm = 25.4;//Inc is inches
    final double ft_TO_cm = 30.48;
    final double mi_TO_km = 1.60934;

    double factor=1;//initialize with 1
```

But I am still not sure that what is the check you are using if the user input is 'ml'.

Comment: please click on answer sign  which is shown disabled near my answer

Comment: I would but it's not letting me. Says I don't have the required 15 reputation.

Comment: @jay No worries
Happy Coding

Comment: thanks! you saved me a tons of time trying to figure out the problem.

Comment: @jay this isn't really an answer so don't get too excited, all its doing is hiding your mid understanding of how the code works and its covering some serious fundamental design errors